# Access Promisearray directly

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I try to access a DS.PromiseArray directly in handlbars ember, but i never get a value on the output. The output on the page is always "DS.PromiseArray:ember321,1" for the first line, and the content of the array if i loop over it with #each. But there is no output if i try to access it directly with the index 0, but i also get no error message. it's also unimportant if i choose 0 or 9 as index, just no output.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return Ember.Object.create({user: this.store.find('user',{status:"active"}), job: this.store.find('job')});
  }
});

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <h2>{{user}},{{user.length}}</h2>

    <h2>{{user.0.name}}</h2>
    <h2>{{user.[0]}}</h2>
    <h2>{{user.[0].name}}</h2>    
    <ul>
      {{#each user}}
        <li>
          <label>{{name}}</label>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>
```

Comment: your 'user' is not an array, it is a single object, if you want to return an array, then, in your 'model' hook, warp your Ember.Object.create with [], like [Ember.Object.create...]

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. I startet experimenting with the array because user.name also has no value. But I don't get it, if this is not an array, why is #each delivering the correct output and the value for user DS.PromiseArray? Thank you

Comment: I see, when you do the each user, it is looping through the 'user' property you defined in your model: user: this.store.find('user',{status:"active"}), that will return a promise array.

Comment: Hm, so I still don't know what I'm doing wrong. It can't be that hard to get a value from an array. I really start hating ember.

Comment: I put it in jsbin: http://jsbin.com/vanipayo/1/edit

Comment: use firstOject instead of .[0], like this user.firstObject.name. Or in your controller create a property observing firstObject and use that property.